# adding small delay to forever loop to reduce cpu usage python

Tags: python, cpu-usage

I have a loop that runs forever reading serial data from gps.  If I add a small delay in each iteration does it help to reduce cpu load.  If not any better way to reduce cpu load.

```
while True:
        byteLine = serialport.readline()
        strLine = byteLine.decode("utf-8")

        splitLine = strLine.split()
        sleep(0.2)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There’s no need to add a delay. If your serial port code is properly written, it will pause during readline() with minimal load on the cpu, until a new line is available. That is the correct behavior - wait for a new chunk of data, process it, then begin waiting again immediately. Try it and see how high the CPU load is (you can use `top` in a different terminal for that.).

If you want to reduce the cpu usage further, you should send instructions to the GPS chip to reduce the [update frequency](https://learn.sparkfun.com/tutorials/gps-basics_) (increase the interval between each update that it sends on the serial line). But adding a delay in your main loop won't reduce CPU load significantly, and risks falling behind the GPS updates.

Comment: is that written properly I'm assuming?  rest of the code is just parsing the string and saving to file.

Comment: Your code looks basically right, but I don't know what libraries you're using (e.g., where `serialport` comes from and how it's configured) or what you are trying to achieve. Is your code working OK?

Comment: pretty much working although it is somewhat laggy.  I have another loop running simultanously on the raspberry pi so that might be the problemo aka I think might be the pi having a weakling cpu.

Comment: That doesn’t sound like a tough workload for a Raspberry Pi. Is the other loop very cpu intensive? Are you able to tell whether the other loop runs while this loop is waiting for input (you might be able to tell by disconnecting the GPS so the readline waits forever). Which package are you using for the serial communication? And are you using the  threading or multiprocessing package to do parallel computing? Python can get laggy if the two loops use standard threads and don’t yield control (via sleep or a well-written I/O routine), due to the global interpreter lock. More details would help.